# bogus memory allocation size in RedHat Linux Enterprise 5

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, evince

I am trying to open a pdf file via evince,after I open it and go through the page,Program suddenly jumped out and following error appears in shell ''bogus memory allocation size''
how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try ghostscript or Okular or kpdf or another free viewer.

You could install Foxit or Adobe reader proprietary software for Linux.

You could see if there are updates available for your RHE5 system.

You could report the bug and wait for Red Hat to fix it. :)

Comment: I ve got other softwares to read my pdf file but the thing is I need to fix this error,as my printer is just compatible with this software.

Comment: If available, try both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of evince, and by all means, report the bug to Red Hat.